# Zariski closure and base change for a constant dimensional family

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $R=\mathbb{C}[[t_1,\cdots,t_n]]$, let $S=\mathrm{Spec}(R)$, let $X$ be an integral scheme. Let $d=\mathrm{dim}(X)-n$

Let $\pi\colon X\to S$ be a projective morphism, such that for every $s\in S$, the fiber $X_s$ is equi-dimension $d$.

Let $S_1=\mathrm{Spec}(R/(t_1))$ and let $\pi_1\colon X_1\to S_1$ be the base change, let $X_{\eta_1}$ be the generic fiber of $X_1$.

Does it necessarily hold that $(X_1)_{\mathrm{red}}=(\overline{X_{\eta_1}})_{\mathrm{red}}$?

Comment: You are asking whether the image in $S_1$ of every irreducible component of $X_1$ contains the generic point (drop "projectivity" -- the image of a finite type morphism between Noetherian schemes is locally closed).  By Krull's Hauptidealsatz, every irreducible component of $X_1$ has dimension equal to $\text{dim}(X)-1$.  The image in $S_1$ is irreducible.  The restricted map from the irreducible component to its image has generic fiber dimension equal to $d$.  So the image has dimension equal to $(\text{dim}(X)-1)-d$, i.e., equal to $n-1$.  Thus the image contains the generic point of $S_1$.

Comment: Thanks so much!